# exception when use not() method in Criteria class from spring-data-elasticsearch project

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa

I try to use spring-data-elasticsearch in my project. When I want to query some data, I use `queryForList(CriteriaQuery query, Class<T> clazz)` in `ElasticsearchTemplate`.

But I kept getting `NullPointerException` from below code:

```
List<QueryBuilder> negationFilters = buildNegationFilter(criteria.getField().getName(), criteria.getFilterCriteriaEntries().iterator());
```

This exception only occurred when I want to use `not()` together with `and()`. When I use `not()` alone it works.

here are some of my code:

```
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = new CriteriaQuery(new Criteria()
        .and(new Criteria("symbol").is("1111"))
        .and(new Criteria("code").is("22").not()));


List<xx> sampleEntities = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(criteriaQuery,xx.class);
```

And I suspect maybe source code has bugs:

In `CriteriaFilterProcessor` class,

```
ListIterator<Criteria> chainIterator = criteria.getCriteriaChain().listIterator();

while (chainIterator.hasNext()) {
    QueryBuilder fb = null;
    Criteria chainedCriteria = chainIterator.next();
    if (chainedCriteria.isOr()) {
        fb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        for(QueryBuilder f: createFilterFragmentForCriteria(chainedCriteria)){
            ((BoolQueryBuilder)fb).should(f);
        }
        fbList.add(fb);
    } else if (chainedCriteria.isNegating()) {
        List<QueryBuilder> negationFilters = buildNegationFilter(criteria.getField().getName(), criteria.getFilterCriteriaEntries().iterator());
        if (!negationFilters.isEmpty()) {
            fbList.addAll(negationFilters);
        }
    } else {
        fbList.addAll(createFilterFragmentForCriteria(chainedCriteria));
    }
}
```

In the `else if (chainedCriteria.isNegating())` part , why would it use  `criteria` to get field? I debug it and found  the field of `criteria` would be `null`, but `chainedCriteria` is not.So is this the bug of source code or the way I use is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved with

```
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = new CriteriaQuery(new Criteria()
        .and(new Criteria("symbol").is("1111"))
        .and("code").is("22").not());
```

so wired, still want to know why the code in question cannot work

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue when trying to build "must not exists" filter as suggested in elastic documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html#find-docs-null-values

I have a method `getElasticsearchCriteria` which builds `Criteria` objects one by one. In that case it returns `return new Criteria(fieldName).exists().not();`. And I chain all those objects like so:
`criteria.and(Utils.getElasticsearchCriteria(fieldName, value));`. When all necessary `Criteria` objects are chained I build the query:
`CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = new CriteriaQuery(criteria, pageable);`

And finally when trying to use such `CriteriaQuery` in `search` method of `ElasticsearchOperations` I am getting an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.Field.getName()" because the return value of "org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.Criteria.getField()" is null
```

Honestly after all my "adventures" with this framework, I came to the conclusion that the most convenient way of using it is to just go with `NativeQuery` and forget about `CriteriaQuery`. I know it looks much more complex, but usually all the methods mirror real Elastic methods from the docs. It simplifies the process of query creation a lot as the community of Elastic itself is much bigger than the one of Spring data elasticsearch framework. I ended up refactoring half of my methods from `CriteriaQuery` to `NativeQuery` as client requirements get more complex.